# How add variable to search.php in Opencart

Tags: php, variables, search, opencart

I have code for dissable Add to cart button, when stock status for product is zero.
But in Search.PHP missing variable for check stock status:

```
$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
```

Full code for check stock status is:

```
'price'       => $price,
'quantity'     => $product_id['quantity'],
'stock_status' => $product_id['stock_status'],

$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
$this->data['product_info'] = $product_info;
```

Can somebody help me with this? I am not programmer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First add variable to `product/search.php` controller after `product_id` around line 252

```
'quantity_available' => $result['quantity'],
```

Now use this variable to check quantity inside `search.tpl` and wrap your `add to cart div inside the if block`
like this

```
<?php if($product['quantity_available'] > 0 ) { ?>
      <div class="cart"><input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" /></div>
<?php } ?>
```

you will have to edit some javscript on `search.tpl` to handle the dynamic changes done by js while someone click on `list/grid` ( search `cart` in that file and realize what changes you will need to make )

While you are doing you also might want to do same thing with manufacture page also

Comment: Code for search.tpl I have and its working. I used it at other pages..Category, Product etc.<br/>

Comment: Code for search.tpl I have and its working. I used it at other pages..Category, Product etc.<br/> But when I use my code i get error <code>Notice: Undefined variable: product_id in search.php at line 263 and 264. At this line is different variable.

Comment: @user3114890 concept is same you might need to changes some variable names. you will need to try something on your own. i have given you solution for `search` page you can use this as reference and do it for other pages.